# MongoId: How to specify relationship correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am new to MongoId. I saw the document by using embeds_many and embedded_in. Just wonder do I need to use it as a pair?

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :band
end
```

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK python Django is the only framework that doesn't require you to define any relation in both sides... any other framework require you to define the relation on both sides of the relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many) is fairly clear on this:

> The parent document of the relation should use the `embeds_many` macro to indicate it has n number of embedded children, where the document that is embedded uses `embedded_in`.
>   [...]
>
> > *Definitions are required on both sides to the relation in order for it to work properly.*

So yes, you need both or it won't work properly.